# Can I move storybook directory to prjroot/build/storybook? (in React Native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, storybook

I'm intoroducing storybook to my React Native project.

Default storybook directory is located at the root of project as `prjroot/storybook/`.

But I wanna place it to `prjroot/build/storybook/`, because I wanna write the storybook config files in TypeScript, and build it into `prjroot/build/storybook/` .

Is there any ways to make storybook recognize the moved path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the `outDir` option to your Typescript config.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/",
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that configuring the `rootDirs` may also be useful if you want to specify the source directories.

https://storybook.js.org/configurations/typescript-config/#tsconfigjson

**EDIT:** in your specific case, using [react-native-storybook-loader](https://github.com/elderfo/react-native-storybook-loader), you have to configure it:

```
"prestorybook": "rnstl --outputFile ./build/storybook/storyLoader.js --pattern \"**/*.story.tsx\" --searchDir ./App"
```

- outputFile with the new path
- pattern to scan .tsx files
- searchDir can be useful to ignore node_modules and prevent conflict

Comment: I know it, but I wanna know how to recognize the position by storybook.

Comment: By adding `-c build/storybook` to the storybook run command ?

Comment: Do you have an error ? How do you start storybook ?

Comment: `-c build/storybook`, but it does not manage `storyLoader` in TS source properly. Does it work in your project to write storybook config files in TS?

Comment: @Taichi I updated my answer, I also pushed my playground on GitHub, not so clean but maybe it can help you: https://github.com/JulienMalige/story-book-typescript-loader-demo

Comment: @Taichi thanks to accept my answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Please wait until Saturday because it's my sub project.

Comment: It still not supported natively because of metro (https://storybook.js.org/basics/writing-stories/#loading-stories-dynamically)